# jQuery UI chained select-menu. Form resets when button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select-menu

I am using a chained select-menu to guide the visitor trough some questions. This works like a charm, however, in the end the user has to click a button to send all values to a PHP-script. This also works without a problem, however, when the page reloads (because the button sends the form to the same page), all fields are hidden again and this is not what i want.

I would like the chained selection menu's to be shown when items in them are "selected" when the page reloads. Using PHP i simply test if a field was selected and add that status to the select-menu. But they remain hidden until you manually select everything again.

I think it's just a minor adjustment in the JS-part. But my limited knowledge of JS leaves me without a solution.

**Sources**

- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XkCsU/)
- [Chainedselection script](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/blob/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/dependency.html)
- [jQuery UI and selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the form submits to itself the values the user chose will be available in either `$_GET` or `$_POST` (depending on whether the `action` of your form is `get` or `post`).

The best approach would then be to use those values to set the `selected` attribute on the appropriate `<option>` node using something like this.

```
$selectedC1Value = '';
<? if isset($_POST['c1']) { ?>
    $selectedC1Value = $_POST['c1'];
<? } ?>

<select name="c1" id="c1" >
    <option value="" <? if ($selectedC1Value == '') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>
        --
    </option>
    <option value="age" <? if ($selectedC1Value == '') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>
        Age
    </option>
    <option value="education" <? if ($selectedC1Value == '') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>
        Education
    </option>
    <!-- etc -->
</select>
```

This would have to be repeated for each `<select>` in your `<form>`.

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP to add "selected" to the option nodes. However, when the page refreshes (because of the form submit) the "selected" options are there, but they are not shown.

Comment: In that case all you should have to do is refactor your JS to call the same method you're calling on change when the page loads.  I changed your fiddle to show this with the first of the `selectmenu` widgets - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/kLDcL/.  You have to do an explicit call of this sort on page load, `selectmenu` isn't going to run your `change` function automatically.

Comment: I've posted this question on multiple forums and tried (as a newbie to JS) for days. You helped me a lot! Thanks, i accepted the answer and upvoted.

May i ask one more question? There is one more field that needs to be shown, i am trying as i am writing this post, but my mind is a blur right now. Could you see please check out: http://jsfiddle.net/kLDcL/1/ 

Again thanks a lot!

Comment: I think i solved it: http://jsfiddle.net/kLDcL/2/ Thanks a lot, you saved me some headaches.

Comment: One more small question.. I would like to show the button ONLY when select name="map[]" and select name="mapb[]" have been selected. Is that possible?